# && operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

While looking through some code (javascript), I found this piece of code:

```
<script>window.Bootloader && Bootloader.done(["pQ27\/"]);</script>
```

What I don't understand is what the `&&` is doing there, the code is from Facebook and is obviously minified and/or obfuscated, but it still does the same thing.

tl;dr: What does the `&&` operator do here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`&&` makes sure that the `Bootloader` function/object exists before calling the `done` method on it.  The code takes advantage of boolean short circuiting to ensure the first expression evaluates to true before executing the second.  See the [short-circuit evaluation wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) entry for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: There are no classes in JavaScript. Bootloader would be a function or object

Comment: It does not "make sure" *Bootloader* is either a function or an object, it just tests if the *window* object has a *Bootloader* property whose value is truthy. If so, it then assumes that it is callable.

Answer (score 19):

```
window.Bootloader && Bootloader.done(["pQ27\/"]);
```

it is equivalent to:

```
if(window.Bootloader) {
  Bootloader.done(["pQ27\/"]);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`&&` is an `AND` operator, just like most everywhere else.  There is really nothing fancy about it.

Most languages, JavaScript included, will stop evaluating an `AND` operator if the first operand is false.

In this case, if `window.Bootloader` does not exist, it will be undef, which evaluates to false, so JavaScript will skip the second part.

If it is true, it continues and calls `Bootloader.done(...)`.

Think of it as a shortcut for `if(window.Bootloader) { Bootloader.done(...) }`

Answer (score 3):

also && operator returns the first encountered value of this kind:
null, undefined, 0, false, NaN, ""

ex:
if

```
var1 = 33
var2 = 0 
var3 = 45

var1 && var2 && var3
returns 0
```