# JavaScript function call passes x && y as parameters

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [&& operator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720645/operator-in-javascript)

In the sample code of the [ExtJS web desktop demo](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/desktop/desktop.html) there is the following call:

```
this.setActiveButton(activeWindow && activeWindow.taskButton);
```

to method:

```
setActiveButton: function(btn) {
    if (btn) {
        btn.toggle(true);
    } else {
        this.items.each(function (item) {
            if (item.isButton) {
                item.toggle(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of the `&&` in the function call?

Comment: @TheZ not really accurate in JavaScript. The value of an `&&` is not necessarily a boolean value.  It can be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to make sure that, before trying to find a property on an object referenced by the variable "activeWindow", the variable actually does reference something.  If it's `null` (or a few other things; we'll assume the code knows that it's either an object reference or `null`), that would cause an exception. This way, the function is passed either the button reference (whatever that is), or `null`.

To put it another way, it's the same as this:

```
this.setActiveButton(activeWindow != null ? activeWindow.taskButton : null)
```

The `&&` operator in JavaScript is kind-of special compared to the `&&` in C or Java or other languages like that.  In JavaScript, the left side is evaluated first. If that value is "falsy" (`null`, `undefined`, `false`, zero, or an empty string), then that's the value of the expression. Otherwise, the value of the expression is the value of the right-hand side.

Comment: except that activeWindow or activeWindow.taskButton can also be `undefined`, `false`, empty string, or `0` and it will pass false.

Comment: @jbabey yes that's true - that's what I meant by "or a few other things", and by that qualifying assumption that the code knows it's either an object reference or null.

Answer (score 1):

See [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for additional information regarding this method.

> The short-circuit expression x Sand y (using Sand to denote the
>   short-circuit variety) is equivalent to the conditional expression if
>   x then y else false; the expression x Sor y is equivalent to if x then
>   true else y.

Comment: Not true in JavaScript - it's not really a **boolean** operator. The *value* of the overall expression is either the value of the left side or the value of the right side, as determined by the "truthiness" of the left side.

Comment: Not that it matters since it has been closed but I have updated my answer to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @RobB Thank you, but the Pointy's reply arrived earlier, so I'll mark his as the correct one. Still +1ed you.