# What does the '&&' expression mean in this snippet of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ampersand

Hi, I recently got a piece of JavaScript code snippet from [here](http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/).

Could someone please explain how this statement works: `(jq=jq.slice(1)).length && hidenext(jq);`in the function below?

```
(function hidenext(jq){
    jq.eq(0).fadeOut("fast", function(){
        (jq=jq.slice(1)).length && hidenext(jq);
    });
})($('div#bodyContent a'))
```

Comment: The answer is here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Most generally, it's a logical AND.

Comment: possible duplicate of [&& operator in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720645/operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, as the result isn't used, the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) is used as a kind of short `if`.

It's the same as

```
if ((jq=jq.slice(1)).length) hidenext(jq);
```

It uses the fact that the second part won't be evaluated if the first one doesn't evaluate as true.

Answer (score 2):

It means that `hidenext(jq)` will only be called if `jq` (now set to the return value of `jq.slice(1)` has a `length` > 0. Because `&&` is short-circuited, evaluation is halted if the first operand is falsy.