# What means var && var in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I wanna know what means the following line in javascript:

```
$variable1 && $variable2
```

The line is exactly like a said, without nothing more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720645/operator-in-javascript

Comment: $variable1 and $variable2 are 2 bool values and its checking if they both are true

Comment: @Krishna They aren't necessarily boolean values

Comment: Are you sure this isn't PHP? Javascript variables don't normally start with `$` unless they are jQuery objects (that is, NOT boolean)

Comment: -1 because I suspect you've confused your languages

Comment: @Krishna the values _may_ or _may_ not be an instanceof Boolean of course.

Comment: @climbage & Dmitris - true

Comment: A lot of down-votes here, but none of the answers on this page or even the supposed "existing question" describe what the && operator really does--which is to return the expression on left if it can be evaluated as `false`, otherwise return the expression on the right.

Comment: If this really is JS, and the said expressions are not a part of any statement, this does nothing. `&&` operator is executed, but the return value is not used anywhere. Maybe you'd post some more code around this line?

Comment: Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rzs6/), there is a `a && b` on a line alone, though it's a part of a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $variable1 && $variable2

"Do $variable1 AND $variable2 BOTH equate to true?"

Answer (score 0):

`$variable1` and `$variable2` are 2 bool values (rightly pointed in comments not always) and its checking if they both are true.

They can also be a jQuery selector's length .. For example:

```
   var $variable1 = someselector.length;
    if($variable1)
    {
        //Some code
    }
```

in the above statement length is an int.. but used to check if the selector exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

$variable1 AND $variable2

&&- logical AND